# Codeigniter - Appended Array items lost when post to controller

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, codeigniter

I have a view page

```
$nameArray = array('name' => 'Formname', 'id' => 'Formname');
echo form_open_multipart('controller/file_upload_function',$nameArray);
<table id="companytable" >
    <tr><td><input type="file" id="dummyfile" name="dummyfile"></td></tr>
    <tr>
         <td >
           <label id="addlabel" style="cursor: pointer;">
                        <i class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></label>
        </td>
    <tr>
        <td>  
              <input type="text" name="companyname[]"  class="cmp_textbx" placeholder="Enter Company">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="submit" id="btn_upload" name="btn_upload" value="Save">
        </td>
   </tr>
</table>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

Using Jquery I need to append more 'companyname' fields according to user(On cliking 'add company' label).'companytable' is the id of the table.

```
$("#addlabel").click(function(){
    $("#companytable").append('<tr><td><input type="text" name="companyname[]"  class="cmp_textbx" placeholder="Enter Company"></td></tr>');
});
```

The problem is when I try to submit my view and try to get the array items 'companyname'.

```
$company_items = array();
$company_items = $this->input->post('companyname');
print_r($company_items);
```

I am able to get only the first item of the array that is already given the view page.The appended array item is lost.Can somebody help me, please?

Comment: Your code is working well...

Comment: `echo "<pre>";print_r($_POST);` Try this code on controller/file_upload_function.

Comment: Sorry it still don't work . the print_r($_POST); gives the answer Array
(
    
    [companyname] => Array
        (
            [0] => fgfdg
        )

    [btn_upload] => Save
) That is only the first array item

Comment: See I didn't change anything in your code.. Its working well... [Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4xkrx.png)

Comment: Thanks everyone for your precious time.

Comment: My code wasn't working because of my popup div on the same page. Because of the popup div or its jquery code , the array items wasn't posted correctly.I think I should delete this question.Really sorry for your time.

Comment: Okay... Now its working naa..?

Comment: Its working if I remove the popup div

Comment: Okay ....Good,,,

Answer (score 0):

[image]Your HTML code works fine. The problem is from jquery or add button. if you are using html button tag for that, then you have to use preventDefault() in the jquery like

```
$('.add').click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
$("#companytable").append('<tr><td><input type="text" name="companyname[]"  class="cmp_textbx" placeholder="Enter Company"></td></tr>');
});
```

or you can use input while selecting type as button, for this you don't need any changes for your code.

Comment: Thanks @prasanna puttaswamy for your response. Actually I'm using a label not a button for add company. Sorry for the misleading infn.

Comment: can u add complete form in question along with jquery?

Comment: @Gyandeep Sharma  I've made the edits on the question. Please review it.